# Is it possible to use Java's ProcessBuilder with virtual files?

Tags: java, processbuilder, vfs, treetagger

I'm currently working integrating Heideltime, currently a standalone application, into a web application that gets deployed with Wildfly. 
I've rewritten much of the code to use JBoss VFS instead of regular Files, but I've gotten stuck when it comes to Heideltime's dependency on TreeTagger, another standalone application.

Heideltime uses Java's ProcessBuilder and Runtime.getRuntime().exec to run TreeTagger from its path on a local file system:

e.g.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/treetagger/bin/tree-tagger /path/to/treetagger/lib/parameter/file /path/to/input/file -no-unknown");
```

but I need to run TreeTagger using virtual files as input and without depending on a user having TreeTagger installed on his/her own computer.

Is there a way to run a process with virtual files? If not, is there some analog to ProcessBuilder for VFS? A VirtualProcessBuilder, if you will?